# is there a way to set a location as not discovered?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I am looking for a way (mod, console command, savegame edit) that allow me to mark a location (that was found/discovered) as unfound (not discovered).

Many times I find locations that I want to investigate later, but later I dont remember which one it was...

Answer (score 3):

**There's no console command that I could find on the wiki.**

Doing a google search gave me [this](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/857741-help-wanto-reverse-show-all-map-markers/) forum link, where somebody is trying to do something vaguely similar, and the closest thing to a usable response was to try and edit the save game file, which I don't know how to do, and I'm assuming you don't either considering you're asking this question, so I think you're out of luck trying to do the specific thing you want.

**However, to answer your deeper question**

You might want to look into the console command ["PlaceLocationMarker"](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Gamebryo_console_commands_%28all%29). I've never used this, and you want to save your game before using it, but supposedly it lets you add new locations markers, and choose the colour? So theoretically, instead of marking a location not discovered, you could put your own location marker there, in a different colour, with the name "look at this again later", assuming that's how it works, and they stay on your map after you save and reload, and you can figure out how to get it working, etc.

Also, again unfortunately, even if that does work, there doesn't seem to be a good way to remove a specific marker, only a command called "ClearLocationMarkers" so you might end up with a bunch of markers saying "look at this again later" when you have, in fact, already looked at it again later.

Comment: @peper757 Just be aware that the moment you open the console you won't get any achievements anymore until you exit and restart the game. It does also not retroactively reward any achievements gained while the block is active. Just in case you care about it...

Comment: @Assylum I hate to tell you, but I don't.

Comment: @peper757 Then don't. No need to be snarky.

Comment: @Assylum I'm not. Stop assuming I'm being snarky.

Comment: I cant make it work `placelocationmarker 5 5 0 test5`, any tips?